# Kerberos auth with Apache httpcomponents (httpclient5)

Tags: java, authentication, httpclient, kerberos, java-17

I want to migrate from Apache httpclient (v3.x and Java 8) to httpcomponents (httpclient5 and Java 17) and move away from my NTLM auth to Kerberos. I have not found any example though on how to do this. I am only finding examples of v4.x and below. Any ideas how to do this in v5.x? Is it even possible?

A rough version of my code currently:

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider;
RequestConfig requestConfig;
credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials(user, pass, host, domain));
requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setTargetPreferredAuthSchemes(Collections.singletonList(AuthSchemes.NTLM)).build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
```

Comment: According to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/understanding-http-authentication)  the authentication scheme you are searching for is named `Negotiate` - but I am not sure if this is still used as it was developed for IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going for the Spring based approach (it is a Spring project either way), which is cleaner and easier, as seen in [this simple example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos/blob/main/spring-security-kerberos-samples/sec-client-rest-template/src/main/java/demo/app/Application.java).